# How to use AWS Parameter Store Build Wrapper Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, aws-parameter-store

I want to use the **AWS Parameter Store Build Wrapper Jenkins plugin** in my build.

https://plugins.jenkins.io/aws-parameter-store/

Above is the link to that plugin. The issue is I didn't find any proper source on how to use that plugin in the `jenkinsfile`.

When I installed that plugin to my local Jenkins, I couldn't see how to configure that plugin in any jenkins build configuration page as well.

If anyone can shed some light on this issue, that would be great.

My ultimate goal is to access some things from the AWS Parameter store. If there's any other way that I can achieve this, I'm more than happy to use that way instead of this plugin as well.